# В Laravel Есть массив список стран, в каком месте лучше всего его сохранить?

Tags: php, laravel

Где объявлять массивы список стран, список временных зон и т. д
чтобы потом их использовать в различных контролерах и html  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854030/laravel-where-to-store-global-arrays-data-and-constants

Comment: Можно и в БД для удобства вместо статики, и использовать кэширование чтобы каждый раз не лазить туда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для laravel есть удобная [либа](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries) для получения стран в удобном синтаксисе коллекций.

Вместе со странами можно получать разную информацию для каждой страны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лично я очень доволен библиотекой.